# Using Websockets with Azure Websites - Error during WebSocket handshake

Tags: asp.net, azure, websocket

I am using Azure websites. In my ASP Net MVC project I created a websocket server and client. When trying to call my server I get

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://binfx.azurewebsites.net/WebSocketServer.ashx' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

My server class is:

**WebSocketServer.ashx**

```
public class WebSocketServer : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Hello World");
            context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new MicrosoftWebSockets());
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Not a websocket response!");
            context.Response.StatusCode=400;    
        }
    }
}
```

My client code is:

**Index.cshtml**

```
 window.onload = function () {
    var conversation = $('body');
    var localHost = window.document.location.host;
    var url = "ws://" + localHost + "/WebSocketServer.ashx"; 
    if (window.WebSocket) {
        var ws = new WebSocket(url);
        ws.onmessage = function (response) {
            conversation.append(createSpan('Response:' + response.data));
        }
        ws.onopen = function (response) {
            ws.send('message!');
            conversation.append(createSpan('Azure CONNECTED'));
        }
        ws.onerror = function (e) {
            conversation.append(createSpan("There are connection issues"));
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Your browser does not support instant messaging. You need to regularly refresh your browser in order to receive updates");
    }
}
```

I have enabled using Websockets in Azure Portal

[Enabling using Websockets in Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcIJT.png)

Thanks for your ideas!